# Tabela Hash com método quadrático

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados, hash

Estou implementando uma tabela hash com método de exploração quadrática. A minha dúvida é em relação à posição 0 do vetor utilizado para implementação da tabela. Segue o código abaixo:

```
public boolean inserir(Pessoa item) {
    int valorHash = hash(item.getCelular());
    int contador = 1;
    int inicialHash = valorHash;

    while(bancoDados[valorHash] != null && !(bancoDados[valorHash].getCelular().equals(-1))) {
        valorHash += (contador*contador);
        contador++;
        valorHash %= tamanhoMax;
    }

    bancoDados[valorHash] = item;

    return true;

}
```

Através desse método a posição 0 nunca será encontrada para uma inserção. Eu devo ignorar essa posição no vetor e trabalhar com o restante ou há alguma forma de fazer o meu valor de Hash (`valorHash`) chegar na posição 0?

OBS: Eu utilizo o número de celular de uma pessoa para gerar o `valorHash` em outro método. Quando uma pessoa é removida da minha tabela eu substituo por outra pessoa, só que com um número de celular inválido (-1), para indicar que aquela posição está disponível.

Comment: Provavelmente está me faltando um pouco de background teórico, mas não entendo porque uma tabela hash iria querer armazenar um elemento em uma posição que não fosse a do próprio hash, afinal, como alguém vai conseguir encontrar os dados de forma confiável depois? Também não entendi o telefone com `-1`, por que não simplesmente atribuir `null`? No mais, acredito que não tenha nenhum problema deixar o primeiro elemento do vetor sem uso, mas se quiser fazer uso dele é só deslocar o resultado subtraindo 1 do hash na hora de armazenar e na hora de recuperar de do vetor.

Answer (score 0):

A posição 0 da sua tabela será encontrada para a inserção sem problemas, sempre que o valor do hash de um objeto for um múltiplo do tamanho da tabela, por exemplo, vamos supor que você tenha uma tabela de 17 posições, e o hash inicial tenha sido 12, mas houve uma colisão, então o próximo hash será h=(12+1*1)%17=13, se também houver uma colisão na posição 13, o próximo hash será h=(13+2*2)%17=0, note que o resto da divisão de 17 por 17 é 0, o mesmo aconteceria se em algum momento o hash fosse 34 ou 51, que são múltiplos de 17.